# How to pass a component as a parameter into an Angular Material dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried to configurate my openDialog() method passing the component as a parameter. My goal is to get a single method for differents dialogComponents, just changing the parameter when i call the method from a service.

Service :

```
openDialog(component: ComponentType<any>): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(component, {
      width: '500px'
    });
```

Component :

```
openDeleteDialog(PopupPostComponent) {
    this.userService.openDialog(PopupPostComponent);
  }
```

The dialog popups but blank with the following error :
No component factory found for undefined. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
My PopupPostComponent is already added in entryComponents.
My app works well the normal way with the PopupPostComponent declared directly in the openDialog() method.
Am i trying an impossible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.module.ts file, try added the name of the popup component to the entryComponents array.  It's found inside the @NgModule function.  Make sure you import the popup component also.  That should resolve that error.